# MYSQL reduce column length without changing datatype

Tags: mysql

Can we change the size of a LONGTEXT column in mysql without changing the datatype?

Comment: Please try to improve your question by adding more information. If not, it will be closed as "Unclear what your're asking." Which kind of data type?

Comment: And, of course, what is the size change?

Comment: The size of my table is 606mb.I want to reduce the size of my table.So i have decided to replace the data in one of the columns of the table with "-".Even after the update i am seeing the same size.how  to reduce the table size with out changing the data type   of it ? The data type  is longtext.

Comment: @saiteja that is really a different question, which has been answered before, see e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193456/how-can-i-reclaim-space-after-nulling-out-longtext-records-on-mysql

Answer (score 1):

If you change the column length you still have to specify the data type in the ALTER TABLE statement, as well as `NOT NULL`, `DEFAULT` and `COMMENT` unless you want to use the defaults (i.e. `NULL DEFAULT NULL` without any comment):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  col1 VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a' COMMENT 'My favourite column'
);

ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY COLUMN col1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a' COMMENT 'My favourite column';
```

Comment: The datatype i am using it Longtext i should reduce the size without changiing the datatype

Comment: @saiteja - `LONGTEXT` is a variable length datatype.  N bytes of text occupies N+4 bytes (plus overhead) on disk.  What do you want to reduce??